# Java application properties file

Tags: java

I need to write a standalone [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) application which will have a embedded HTTP server. I need to call a [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) page deployed locally with the application. The HTML page should display the properties listed in *.properties file deployed with the application. I should be able to change the properties value as well from the HTML page Is there a way to do it?

Am I clear?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen (re: edits) - do you really think it's necessary to link to definitions of Java and HTML on a programming website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use embedded [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty).

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the part you're not sure about is how to read the properties file.  Though really I don't think your question *is* that clear as to what part you want help with.

In *general* it's straightforward - you can create a java.util.Properties object (with the default constructor), then get hold of an InputStream for your properties file (either using FileInputStream if it's really on the filesystem, or [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) if it's in a JAR).  Once you've got this then you can just call [Properties.load()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) to populate the properties object.

From there you can iterate over this object to get all the keys and values and print them out.  You'd obviously need to do this with some kind of server-side technology such as JSP, rather than static HTML.

As for the embedded server, Ramon is right that Jetty should be more than sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a servlet class which has the `doGet()` implemented to read the properties file using `Properties#load()`, stores it in the request scope using `HttpServletRequest#setAttribute()`, forwards the request to a JSP file using `RequestDispatcher#forward()`. Finally map this servlet in web.xml on an url-pattern like `/propertieseditor`.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties"));
request.setAttribute("properties", properties);
request.getRequestDispatcher("propertieseditor.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

2) Create a JSP file which uses JSTL `c:forEach` to iterate over the properties key-value pairs, generating a HTML `input type="text"` element everytime.

```
<form action="propertieseditor" method="post">
    <c:forEach items="${properties}" var="property">
        ${property.key} <input type="text" name="${property.key}" value="${property.value}"><br>
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

3) Add a `doPost()` method to the servlet as created in 1) and write logic which gathers all property key-value pairs from the request parameter map and stores it back in the file.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Map<String, Object> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
    properties.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
properties.store(new FileOutputStream(new File(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("file.properties").toURI())));
response.sendRedirect("propertieseditor.jsp");
```

Finally use the propertieseditor by [http://localhost/webapp/propertieseditor](http://localhost:post/webapp/propertieseditor). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Commons Configuration' for both loading and saving properties. Check http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Using_PropertiesConfiguration and http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Saving